# zle read first word in line?

Tags: zsh, zle

Let us say:

```
% ls ./ _
```

when `foo` is called, where `_` is the cursor position.

```
foo(){
    echo $COMMAND
}
zle -N foo
```

How can `COMMAND` be set such that `foo` will write out the 'command' (as in, the first word of the line - doesn't need to list or anything where `&&` and the like is used) that was issued?

Answer (score 2):

So you want the `ls` bit from the beginning of the current line? Let's see what's set by `zsh`…

```
% foo(){ set > whatallisset }
% zle -N foo
% bindkey "^W" foo
% ls ./  # here I mash control+w, etc
% fgrep 'ls ./' whatallisset
BUFFER='ls ./ '
LBUFFER='ls ./ '
```

So we're probably looking at parsing one of those variables for the "first word", so assuming `BUFFER` is most appropriate, and then after delving through the `zshexpn(1)` docs and looking for "split" related things:

```
foo(){ echo -n ${${(z)BUFFER}[1]} }
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer that I can actually follow through instead of just giving the concluding one-liner! :)

Comment: If `$BUFFER` is a single word, then it returns just the first letter. Is there a way to address this to get the whole word when it's just a single word?

Comment: @spex `${${(zA)BUFFER}[1]}` should fix that. The `A` flag converts the substitution into an array expression, even if it otherwise would be scalar.

Answer (score 2):

You have access to a number of variables in [user-defined widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#User_002dDefined-Widgets), in particular `BUFFER` which contains the content of the line (or more broadly, the whole buffer, which can be multiline).

How to extract the first word from `BUFFER` depends on your definition of words. In this context, the most useful definition is probably based on shell syntax, which is available through the `z` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
first_word=${${(z)BUFFER}[1]}
```

Other sensible definitions are to use whitespace-delimited words, or words consisting of [`$WORDCHARS`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-WORDCHARS). There are [movement commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Movement) for that, but while you can call them via the `zle` builtin and watch `CURSOR` move, it would be easier to manually split the string `$BUFFER`.

In completion widgets, the words of the command for which the completion is taking place are in the `words` [parameter](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Special-Parameters).